# iOS Safari - disable scroll / bounce but retain zoom

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, css, safari

I'm creating a web-app for iOS Safari and have run into a slight hurdle.

My web-app only takes up 1024x768 of screen real estate and therefore does not need scrolling, but it does need to be able to zoom (it's a PDF annotator).

I have used a plugin called iNoBounce (https://github.com/lazd/iNoBounce/) which successfully removes scrolling from the page by firing an `evt.preventDefault()` on the touchmove/touchstart events.  This is great.

What this does though, is remove zoom events as well as scroll events. Is there a way to remove scrolling/elastic bouncing but to retain zoom on iOS safari?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve this issue by listening to some values on the touch event object, specifically `changedTouches.length` and `scale`.

First I set a global variable for zoomLevel at the top of the document `var zoomLevel = 1`

Next, I replaced `evt.preventDefault()` in iNoBounce with:

```
if(evt.changedTouches.length === 1 && zoomLevel <= 1){
    evt.preventDefault();
}
if(evt.changedTouches.length > 1){
    zoomLevel = evt.scale;
}
```

This looks at how many fingers are being used and if the page scale is not 100%, then acts accordingly.